# how to write to excel?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I m trying to write something to excel , I tried something but doesn't work .I don't know how to do that .

```
 XSSFWorkbook wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook();     
 Sheet shee = wb1.createSheet("Data");         
 FileOutputStream fileOut = new 
 FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User_2\\Desktop\\video.xlsx");
        wb1.write(fileOut);
         d.get("http://freevideolectures.com/Course/3680/Pentaho-BI");
         java.util.List<WebElement> cl = 
         d.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='lecture_menu']/li/a"));
                            for (WebElement wel : cl) {
                                 String href = wel.getAttribute("href");
                                  System.out.println(href);
```

I want the to print the output in the excel , Need help !

Comment: I dont know how exactly , i am new to selenium and programming , can u help me ??

Comment: @DebanjanB can u help me out ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link will definitely help you: [Read and write in Excel](https://www.guru99.com/all-about-excel-in-selenium-poi-jxl.html)